# What do you use to keep track of and map network endpoints and ports?

Tags: networking

I’m working with a small office who’s moving into a used space. The previous tenants punched their wall ports for the different offices and floors in a random order in the network rack and it drives my OCD mad, but not mad enough to repunch 64 ports.

Right now I’ve labeled the wall ports with their corresponding punch panel labels and made a spreadsheet logically assigning the various punch ports with my switch. My problem is keeping track of these three sets of informations:

- Physical location of network cable endpoint
- location of corresponding punch panel port
- assigned switch & port number

I have not worked with other large enterprise network techs in this aspect, so I’m wondering if there’s got to be a better way of mapping this info and keeping it up to date without editing PDFs of floor plans and using excel spreadsheets. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with using a spreadsheet? I mean, how often are you making changes?